# If pattern matching with `Maybe a` result

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Following code illustrates my intention. I want to pattern match, if it doesn't result is `Nothing`, if matches result is `Just something`

```
data MyData = 
      A Int
    | B String
    | C


ifA (A i) = Just i 
ifA _     = Nothing

ifB (B str) = Just str
ifB _     = Nothing

ifC C = Just () 
ifC _ = Nothing 



mbMult3 i = Just (i*3)

concWorld str = Just (str ++ "World")

example1 v = ifA v >>= mbMult3

example2 v = ifB v >>= concWorld

-- example2 (B "Hello ,") == Just "Hello, World"
-- example2 (A 3) == Nothing
```

Are there other ways to do `ifA` `ifB` `ifC`.

**Edit:**

1. I suspect that `lens` library might have something. But I know nothing about `lens` for now.
2. Updated `ifC`

Comment: Is there any problem with your current version?

Comment: It works as expected but writing those `ifA` `ifB` `ifC` is tedious.

Comment: BTW your `ifC` isn't quite like `ifA` and `ifB`. Perhaps try `Just ()` for it.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Prisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html)<sup>†</sup> from the [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package model this. You can generate prisms for your type using [`makePrisms`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makePrisms), then use [`^?`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:-94--63-) (or its prefix equivalent, [`preview`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:preview)) to access members of the sum type, producing `Nothing` if a different value is provided:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data MyData
  = A Int
  | B String
  | C
  deriving (Show)

makePrisms ''MyData
```

```
ghci> A 42 ^? _A
Just 42
ghci> A 42 ^? _B
Nothing
ghci> C ^? _C
Just ()
```

The nice thing about prisms is that they compose with other optics (e.g. [lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html), [folds](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html), and [traversals](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html)), as well as use them to traverse through nested sum types by composing prisms:

```
ghci> (A 42, C) ^? _1._A
Just 42
ghci> (B "hello", C) ^? _1._A
Nothing
ghci> Just (A 42) ^? _Just._A
Just 42
ghci> Just (B "hello") ^? _Just._A
Nothing
ghci> Nothing ^? _Just._A
Nothing
```

The [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package is fairly complicated, and explaining all of its features is well outside the scope of this answer. If you don’t need much of it, your solution is probably fine. But if you find yourself writing that sort of code a lot, it’s likely that lens can help, as long as you’re willing to accept the steep learning curve and often-confusing type errors.

---

<sup>† More generally, `^?` works on any [`Fold`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html) that produces zero or one value (or more, it just ignores all but the first one), but prisms are specifically designed with sum types in mind, so they are more relevant here.</sup>

Comment: What should I read to master `lens`? I can only find beginner tutorials.

Comment: @DulguunOtgon I think that depends on what you mean by “master”. I mostly learned how to use it by reading the documentation and looking into things as I found I needed them, after learning the basics.

Comment: FTR, you can't actually compose a prism with a lens. What you can do is compose a setter with a setter, and both `Prism` and `Lens` are actually polymorphic types which include `ASetter` as a specialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cute idiom that I use from time to time, since I'm not yet up on my lenses.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MonadComprehensions #-}

example1 v = [ x | A x <- pure v ] >>= mbMult3
```